# Google + YouTube JS API Blocked a frame from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, api, dynamic, youtube

I am working on a site that uses ajax for page transitions. On the home page, I am loading youtube videos and a subscribe button dynamically via javascript. When I transition from the homepage to another page, I am getting the following error:

**Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame**

Anyone run into this when using "single page apps"?

Answer (score 3):

You did not give a whole lot of context but my money is on you are trying to show a youtube video with a "watch" link in an iframe, all you have to do is use an embedded link to display youtube videos in an iframe.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giYeaKsXnsI

vs

https://www.youtube.com/embed/giYeaKsXnsI

Otherwise, youtube will throw cross-origin errors.

I suggest using some regex to pull out the video id (giYeaKsXnsI in the example above) and append that to the end of the embedded URL and pass that as the src attribute in the iframe.